# Default move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class like

```
class MyMatrix {
public:
    MyMatrix() = default;
    MyMatrix(const MyMatrix&) = default;
    ~MyMatrix() = default;

    // some custom methods..

private:
   std::vector<float> data;
}
```

since I have all my data in a vector I thought that RAII should take care of the memory.

My question is: should I also include a `MyMatrix(MyMatrix&&) = default;` line? Would my code benefit from this at all or would I do something wrong if I did?

Comment: You can omit all of those functions, the compiler already knows what to do, assuming there are no other members.

Comment: If you specify copy constructor and destructor then move constructor and move assignment are not default generated by the compiler. You need to mark them as default as you thought or otherwise remove all of those defaults and compiler takes care of everything else.

Comment: Thanks. Someone please make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you provide a *user-declared* copy constructor (or copy assignment operator), neither the *move constructor* nor the *move assignment operator* are declared.

```
MyMatrix(const MyMatrix&) = default; // <- though `defaulted`, it *is* user-declared...
```

If you want your class to benefit from move semantics, in that case, you'll need to declare them by yourself (you can still default them as well). Since you have only members which have well defined copy and move semantics (the vector), the default implementation will be alright.

```
MyMatrix(MyMatrix&&) = default;
```

Adding that declaration would lead to the automatic *deletion* of the copy assignment operator. If you want it you'ld have to declare it as well!

In the end, you could just remove the declaration of the copy constructor and it would perform how you wish it would. (You'ld also have both the move and copy assignment operators automatically defaulted for you).

Here is a [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014) by Howard Hinnant on that matter (with beautiful tables) showing you what the compiler generates -or does not- depending on what you declare.

Answer (score 3):

What you *should* do, is this:

```
class MyMatrix {
public:
   // some custom methods..

private:
   std::vector<float> data;
};
```

All of those defaulted special member functions will be implicitly defined when you don't declare any of them yourself.